# Is there anyway to create an AEM asset report which generates only jcr:primaryType for mentioned path

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have a requirement, when I generate an AEM asset report which provides only jcr:primaryType for the entire selected path folder.

Reference:

| S .No | jcr:primaryType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | nt:unstructured |
| 2 | nt:folder |

Thanks in Advance.

I tried different approaches but not received the expected results.